# Конвертирование JSON-строки

Tags: json, php

Передаю ajax'ом POST-данные и сохраняю в массиве ($arr):

```
﻿﻿user_id_from => 42
user_id_to => 43
date_time => 2012-08-19 23:58:51
subject => Почему?
message => так..
obj_identifier => o19
```

далее вызываю метод json_encode($arr); 
Вот что он мне выводит в результате при получении ответа в клиентском скрипте:

```
... "\u041f\u043e\u0447\u0435\u043c\u0443?","\u0442\u0430\u043a.." ...
```

Если использую вместо кириллицы латиницу, всё ОК.
Кодировка страницы - UTF-8 без BOM. 
Если декодировать эту строку и, например, вывести её на странице, куда отсылается ajax-запрос:

```
var_dump("<h1>json:</h1><pre>",json_decode($arr),"</pre>");
```

то оно показывает всё нормально. 
Однако я не могу декодировать её там, где получаю ответ, поскольку в клиентском скрипте она извлекается как **request.responseText**:

```
var jData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
```

Вероятно, решение есть, но мне оно неизвестно :(
Буду очень признателен за помощь!

Comment: какая версия php?

Comment: Вот именно поэтому я юзаю старый добрый xml в качестве ответов сервера - экономия трафика...) 
Либо переписывай место ответа, либо пиши свою функцию декода из escaped unicode.

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.3

Comment: Похоже, *responseText* ожидается в UTF-8, а на самом деле это Unicode, закодированный в соответствии с  RFC4627 (Json).

По сути здесь "смесь" UTF-16 и ASCII. Если не брать суррогатные пары, то алгоритм декодирования в Unicode (16-bit) очевиден. Каждый "символ" (это либо 1 байт, либо 6 в виде \\uHHHH) это код UCS. Идете по строке, читаете "символ" (получаете 16-bit целое), переводите его (кодируйте) в UTF-8 (сразу в строку результата (от 1 до 3-х байт)). 

С суррогатными парами мороки больше. Про них сами прочитайте. Суть в том, что такая пара кодирует 31-bit(?) целое...

Все, лимит исчерпан.

Comment: В свое время тоже задавался этим вопросом: [Кириллица в json_encode][1].

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/37998/php-%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%B2-json_encode

Answer (score 1):

- Собственно, эскейпинг в этом случае происходит из консервативных и `backward compatibility` соображений, хорошо этот вопрос прокомментировал `Jon Skeet` [**здесь.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207692/utf-8-in-xml-and-json-schema)

> - На мой личный взгляд, не самая плохая идея. Тем более что, судя по [**RFC4627,**](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) этот `JSON` валиден, а значит должен парситься.
> - С еще одной небезынтересной дискуссией по теме можно ознакомиться [**тут.**](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/163934)

- [@Равнодушный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/8603/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) `JSON` с незаэскейпленными юникодными символами - это тоже валидный `JSON`, поэтому не очень понятна фраза про экономию трафика в сравнении с `XML`.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо всем. После хождения по бесчисленным топикам, посвящённым проблемам преобразования символов при работе с JSON, я так и не нашёл однозначного решения проблемы. Зато выяснил, в чём она была в конкретном случае - а именно в том, что среди нескольких подключаемых (require) файлов были те, у которых была выставлена кодировка UTF-8 с BOM (замечу, что я пользуюсь DW, а у него есть такая особенность, - если переключиться с проекта, у которого была другая кодировка, он там может слегка начудить). После того, как убрал BOM всё отлично заработало. 
Надеюсь данный опыт будет полезным для коллег.

Comment: @srgg67, хорошее исследование. Примерно ясно. PHP обнаружив некоторое рассогласование в кодировках, решил "привести все к своему общему знаменателю". 

Вот только другие части системы к этому оказались не готовы.

Comment: А кстати - оно как понимает кодировку того, что там вылезло, когда было указано "c BOM"? Или просто не может её определить и сходит с ума?

Comment: Судя по тексту в Вашем вопросе

    "\u041f\u043e\u0447\u0435\u043c\u0443?",...

кодировка входа utf-8 была определена и текст был успешно перекодирован в Unicode, и вот выход в JSON представлен именно символами Unicode. 

Хотя, начала строки у Вас нет. BOM в utf-8 кодируется 0xef,0xbb, 0xbf и соответствует символу Unicode 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (\\ufeff в Json).

Больше ничего толкового добавить не могу.